# Highest probability of winning in three contestant by guessing special number each having 50% chance to win.

Tags: probability

I am stuck in this question asked in interview. Please help to understand.

In a game of three player each having a base value as
for $A = p, B = q$ and $C = r$.

Each player is allowed to guess special number. If player's guessed number is correct number then same number will be awarded otherwise same number will be deducted from his base value.

Player $A$ guess number $A_x$ and $B$ guess $B_x$. Now player $C$ have to guess special number between $0$ to $r$(both inclusive) which maximize probability of winning the game.

We can assume that player C and both other players each independently have 50% chance to answer correctly.

Guess the minimum number for player C for highest probability of winning the game.
Please help me understand what is minimum special number in all scenario.

Comment: Is there any relationship between p,q & r?

Comment: No, there is no relation between p, q and r.